# How to host a deb/apt repo on CentOS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, debian

I would like to make a mirror of just the puppet client and its dependencies for Ubuntu Precise, but hosted on my CentOS 6 host.

If I do

```
cd /var/ftp
wget -A deb -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=1 http://apt.puppetlabs.com/pool/precise/dependencies/
wget -A deb -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=1 http://apt.puppetlabs.com/pool/precise/main/
```

and then on an Ubuntu Precise add the following to `/etc/yum.repos.d/mypuppet.repo`

```
deb ftp://puppet.example.com precise main
deb ftp://puppet.example.com precise dependencies
```

then I get

```
W: Failed to fetch ftp://puppet.example.com/dists/precise/dependencies/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  '
```

**Question**

Is there a tool or howto on how to host a deb/apt repo on CentOS?

Comment: Out of curiousity...does that file actually exist?  Can you fetch it manually?  If it *does* exist, is your ftp server logging any errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the appropriate tool for this task is `debmirror(1)`, which is available in the CentOS repositories.

Make sure you import the GPG keys of the puppetlabs repository from a keyserver:

```
# gpg --recv-keys 1054B7A24BD6EC30
gpg: requesting key 4BD6EC30 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key 4BD6EC30: public key "Puppet Labs Release Key (Puppet Labs Release Key) <info@puppetlabs.com>" imported
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, classic trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   3  signed:   4  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 3u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:   4  signed:   6  trust: 3-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 1f, 0u
gpg: depth: 2  valid:   1  signed:   1  trust: 1-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 0u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2014-05-11
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Then, grab the packages from their repository:

```
# debmirror --check-gpg --keyring=/path/to/keyring.gpg --method=http \ 
  --root=/ --arch amd64 --dist precise --section main,dependencies   \
  --nosource --host apt.puppetlabs.com --progress /path/to/local/repo
```

This way you ensure the directory structure is correct and all the expected files are present.

Answer (score 4):

You synced only the deb files , you forgot to retrieve package list definition, you can have it at  http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/precise/ .

I really suggest you to sync all the repository with:

```
rsync -av --copy-links --del rsync://apt.puppetlabs.com/packages/apt/ /var/ftp/
```

With Rsync it will easier to keep up to date your files. 
I'm pretty sure if you have deb files AND the package definition it will work .

http://apt.puppetlabs.com/README.txt

have a nice day.